# Why does one complex bits-shifting command not act like some commands with the same logic?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, byte, bit-shift, bit

For example ,for these similar codes when I'm writing it like the first pattern the condition gets true and in the second pattern the condition gets false.

I have watched the values of `mask & (bits >> i)` and `mask` in real-time in the debugger tool and although they were the same the condition returned false.

Why this weird behavior happening?

1:

```
void printLetters(unsigned int bits, unsigned int i) // 0<i<7
{
   unsigned int mask = 0x1;
   unsigned temp;

   temp = mask & (bits >> i);
   if (temp == mask) //the same condition in other way
        printf("true");
}
```

2:

```
void printLetters(unsigned int bits, unsigned int i) // 0<i<7
{
   unsigned int mask = 0x1;

   if (mask & (bits >> i)== mask) //the same condition in other way
       printf("true");`
}
```

Comment: What values are being passed into `bits` and `i`?

Comment: It seems that to get true printed out they can be only `bits=1` and `i=0`.

Comment: Because in 2. `mask & (bits >> i)` needs to be in parentheses for operator precendence. So `(mask & (bits >> i)) == mask`. But in 1. the operator precedence wasn't an issue because  `mask & (bits >> i)` goes into a variable first. Example 2. is effectively `if (mask & ((bits >> i)== mask))`

Comment: The comparison operator `==` has higher precedence that the bitwise and operator `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equal operator `==` precedence is higher than that of the bitwise AND operator `&`.

In the first case the temporary variable `temp` gets the corrected value and the successive comparison give correct result.

In the second example the comparison happen before, than the comparison result is anded bitwise with the `mask`.

Because the comparison gives only 1 or 0 for true or false respectively, if the bit 0 of `(bits >> i)` is set the result will always be true (with `mask==0x1`) and false else.

The code to work must use parenthesis to change the order of evaluation as below:

```
void printLetters(unsigned int bits, unsigned int i) // 0<i<7
{
   unsigned int mask = 0x1;

   if ( (mask & (bits >> i)) == mask) //note brackets
       printf("true");`
}
```